# NestJS : TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to pass the connection parameters to mongodb by enviroment file and I am getting the following error

```
[Nest] 1176  - 12/10/2021 23:34:35   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at MongoService.createMongooseOptions (/Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/src/common/mongo/mongo.service.ts:20:41)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:135:120)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:16:12)
    at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (/Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose/dist/mongoose-core.module.js:135:45)
    at Injector.instantiateClass (/Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:294:55)
    at callback (/Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:43:41)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/Users/Desarrollos/NestJS/nestjs-ventas-negocios/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:119:24)
```

This is the service mongo.service.ts

```
import { MongooseModuleOptions, MongooseOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Configuration } from '../../config/config.keys';
import { ConfigService } from '../../config/config.service';

export class MongoService implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
    constructor( private configService: ConfigService ) {}

    createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {

        const user     = this.configService.get(Configuration.DB_MONGO_USER);
        const password = this.configService.get(Configuration.DB_MONGO_PASSWORD);
        const server   = this.configService.get(Configuration.DB_MONGO_HOST);
        const database = this.configService.get(Configuration.DB_MONGO_DATABASE);

        return {
            uri: `mongodb://${user}:${password}@${server}/${database}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
        };
    }
}
```

And this I import it in the app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: MongoService,
    }),
```

Any suggestion,
thanks,
JM

Comment: Did you search this site for *cannot get property of undefined*? There have been literally hundreds (if not thousands) of previous questions related to the same error asked (and answered) here before. Surely one of them can point out a way for you to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add `@Injectable()` above `MongoService`

Comment: adding @Injectable  I get the following error  : Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MongoService (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the MongooseCoreModule context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need 2 things here:

1. Your `MongoService` needs to be marked with `@Injectable()` so that Nest can read the metadata of the constructor and set up the injection properly
2. If your `ConfigModule` does not have a globally exported `ConfigService`, then in `MongooseModule.forRootAsync()` along with the `useClass` you need to have `imports: [ConfigModule]` so that you can inject the `ConfigService`

Comment: Thanks Jay, I'm obviously connecting something wrong and I can't see it. With @Injectable()  , I get the following error : ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MongoService (?). Please make sure that the argument ConfigService at index [0] is available in the MongooseCoreModule context.

Comment: Did you add the `ConfigModule` to the `MongooseModule.forRootAsync()` options, like I mentioned in point 2?

Comment: The same error : @Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ ConfigService ],
      useClass: MongoService,
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    VentaNegociosModule, 
    ConfigModule
  ],

Comment: You have `imports: [ConfigService]`, not `imports: [ConfigModule]`. You also don't need `inject`

Answer (score 3):

```html
@Module({ 
  imports: [ 
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({ 
      imports: [ ConfigModule ], 
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useClass: MongoService
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

After search for several posts, if you are using nx for nestjs and using esbuild for compiler, you might have this problem. The way to make it work is to change back to webpack, because esbuild is having issue with monorepo.

Ref: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/20546